# Merge the results of 2 unions

Tags: oracle, merge, union

I have an union query with 2 parts. Part 1 calculates the amount of payments of the last month and part 2 calculates the amount of statements of the last month. I use following query

```
  WITH DATA AS(
    (SELECT DA.ID, DDO.CODE, NULL AS PAYMENTS, ABS(SUM(FAT.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY)) AS STATEMENTS --, FPP.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY AS PAYMENTS
    FROM DIM_ACCOUNT  DA 
    JOIN DIM_DATA_OWNER DDO ON DA.DATA_OWNER_ID = DDO.ID
    JOIN FACT_AS_TRANSACTION FAT ON FAT.ACCOUNT_ID = DA.ID
    JOIN DIM_DATE DD ON FAT.VALUE_DATE_ID = DD.ID
    WHERE DD.CAL_DATE >= TO_DATE('2015-09-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND FAT.DEBIT_CREDIT_MARK = 'Debit'
    GROUP BY DA.ID, DDO.CODE
    HAVING SUM(FAT.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY) != 0)
    UNION 
    (SELECT DA.ID, DDO.CODE, ABS(COALESCE(SUM(FPP.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY),0)) AS PAYMENTS, NULL
    FROM DIM_ACCOUNT  DA 
    JOIN DIM_DATA_OWNER DDO ON DA.DATA_OWNER_ID = DDO.ID
    JOIN FACT_PAY_PAYMENT FPP ON FPP.ORDERING_ACCOUNT_ID = DA.ID
    JOIN DIM_PAY_PAYMENT_METHOD DPPM ON DPPM.ID = FPP.PAYMENT_METHOD_ID
    JOIN DIM_DATE DD ON FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID = DD.ID
    WHERE DD.CAL_DATE >= TO_DATE('2015-09-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    GROUP BY DA.ID, DDO.CODE)
    )
    SELECT * FROM DATA
```

This gives following output 
[image: received result]
What I want to show is the statements and payments on 1 line. So this result should be merged to 2 lines:
[image: expected result]
How do you realize this?

Comment: use DISTINCT on ID of each table and try it. like example : SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM TABLE WHERE CONDITION.

Comment: Shouldn't it be better to use a MAX aggregation on payments and statements? and group by the id and code?

Comment: Try to put 0 instead of the NULLs, then make it all a subquery and in the outer query select the MAX of PAYMENTS and STATEMENTS.

Comment: Hi Guli, this can be solve by subquery,amount of payments or 
amount of statements can be  calculated by function with given parameter and then that function can be used in main query.

Comment: Why are you unioning two queries here, not just joining in a single query? With outer join if you might only have data in one of the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you really cannot join it all together in one select statement, this little adaption should work:

```
WITH DATA AS(
(SELECT DA.ID, DDO.CODE, 0 AS PAYMENTS, ABS(SUM(FAT.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY)) AS STATEMENTS --, FPP.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY AS PAYMENTS
FROM DIM_ACCOUNT  DA 
JOIN DIM_DATA_OWNER DDO ON DA.DATA_OWNER_ID = DDO.ID
JOIN FACT_AS_TRANSACTION FAT ON FAT.ACCOUNT_ID = DA.ID
JOIN DIM_DATE DD ON FAT.VALUE_DATE_ID = DD.ID
WHERE DD.CAL_DATE >= TO_DATE('2015-09-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
AND FAT.DEBIT_CREDIT_MARK = 'Debit'
GROUP BY DA.ID, DDO.CODE
HAVING SUM(FAT.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY) != 0)
UNION 
(SELECT DA.ID, DDO.CODE, ABS(COALESCE(SUM(FPP.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY),0)) AS PAYMENTS, 0 AS STATEMENTS
FROM DIM_ACCOUNT  DA 
JOIN DIM_DATA_OWNER DDO ON DA.DATA_OWNER_ID = DDO.ID
JOIN FACT_PAY_PAYMENT FPP ON FPP.ORDERING_ACCOUNT_ID = DA.ID
JOIN DIM_PAY_PAYMENT_METHOD DPPM ON DPPM.ID = FPP.PAYMENT_METHOD_ID
JOIN DIM_DATE DD ON FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID = DD.ID
WHERE DD.CAL_DATE >= TO_DATE('2015-09-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY DA.ID, DDO.CODE)
)
SELECT ID, CODE, SUM(PAYMENTS), SUM(STATEMENTS) FROM DATA
GROUP BY ID, CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, I joined it all in one query. `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is used in case you can have data only in one table.

```
SELECT DA.ID, DDO.CODE, ABS(COALESCE(SUM(FPP.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY),0)) AS PAYMENTS, ABS(SUM(FAT.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY)) AS STATEMENTS 
    FROM DIM_ACCOUNT  DA 
    JOIN DIM_DATA_OWNER DDO ON DA.DATA_OWNER_ID = DDO.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN FACT_AS_TRANSACTION FAT ON FAT.ACCOUNT_ID = DA.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN FACT_PAY_PAYMENT FPP ON FPP.ORDERING_ACCOUNT_ID = DA.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DIM_DATE DD1 ON FAT.VALUE_DATE_ID = DD1.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DIM_DATE DD2 ON FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID = DD.DD2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DIM_PAY_PAYMENT_METHOD DPPM ON DPPM.ID = FPP.PAYMENT_METHOD_ID
    WHERE DD1.CAL_DATE >= TO_DATE('2015-09-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND DD2.CAL_DATE >= TO_DATE('2015-09-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND FAT.DEBIT_CREDIT_MARK = 'Debit'
    GROUP BY DA.ID, DDO.CODE
    HAVING SUM(FAT.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY) != 0 OR SUM(FPP.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY) != 0;
```